# maven profile dependent property

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml

My maven pom looks like this:

```
    <...>
    <profiles>
     <profile>
      <...>
        <id>1</id>
       <properties>
       <MY_VAR>asdf</MY_VAR><...>
    <profile>
      <...>
    <id>2</id>
       <properties>
    <MY_VAR>jklö</MY_VAR><...>
</profiles>
<build>
  <...>
</build>
```

now I want to use the `MY_VAR` property in the major -section in a plugin.
How do I do this.. It is probably a scope problem?

sincerely Paul

Comment: Can you show what you want to do in the plugin section? Whatever you mean in this case?

Comment: I just want to use a property, defined in a profile. But I cant, probably because the property is only visible in this certaint profile.. so i'm searching for a workaround, so i can defind profile depended plugins, but use them in the general build (in some plugins there)